# Filtering rows conditionally within a query to further filter the query result in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I have mostly worked with NoSql dbs but I'm trying my hands at SQL after a very long while. I have a table named invoices.

| id | invoice_type | valid_until |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | quote | 2023-03-10 |
| 02 | quote | 2021-03-10 |
| 03 | reservation | 2022-03-11 |

I'm trying to filter rows on a query param named `type`

1. If `type = reservation`, Return all rows with `invoice_type = reservation`
2. If `type  = quote`, Return all rows with `invoice_type = quote AND valid_until > now()`
3. If `type = undefined || invalid`, Return rows of both types but for rows with `invoice_type = quote`  still filter them out based on the `valid_until` field.

I'm struggling with the 3rd rule, the idea is to get all rows and then apply the filter for `valid_until` only on the rows with `type = quote`

Expected Output

```
GET api/invoices?type=quote
  { id: 01, invoice_type: 'quote', valid_until: '2023-03-10' }

GET api/invoices?type=reservation
  { id: 03, invoice_type: 'reservation', valid_until: '2022-03-11' }

GET api/invoices
  [
    { id: 01, invoice_type: 'quote', valid_until: '2023-03-10' },
    { id: 03, invoice_type: 'reservation', valid_until: '2022-03-11' }
  ]
```

Current solution is

```
const invoices = await knex('invoices').where((builder) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'quote':
      builder.where({ type }).where('valid_until', '>', 'now()');
      break;
    case 'reservation':
      builder.where({ type });
      break;
    default:
      console.log(type);
      builder
        .where({ type: 'quote' })
        .where('valid_until', '>', 'now()')
        .orWhere({ type: 'reservation' });
      break;
  }
});
```

It's working but I was hoping to achieve this purely through SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `where` clause in a parameterized query can do all this. Here it is. `:type` is the parameter.

```sql
select * from invoices
where
    (:type = 'reservation' AND invoice_type = 'reservation')
 OR (:type = 'quote' AND invoice_type = 'quote' AND valid_until > now())
 OR (:type in ('undefined', 'invalid') AND case
       when invoice_type = 'quote' then valid_until > now() 
       else true 
      end
    );
```

Comment: If `type` is undefined || invalid won't the check `valid_until > now()` be applied to reservation type invoices as well ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. My omission. I will update the answer.